# php intl not supported by hosting provider

Tags: cakephp, plugins, intl

i have planned to install cakephp for my website. however php intl is not supported by the host (a requirement for cakephp). there are cakephp intl plugins available in git. Is it ok to use the intl plugins, what are the implications of not using regular intl dll

Comment: Contact to your host provider to install the INTL extension.

Answer (score 1):

The [cake-intl](https://github.com/hraq/cake-intl) plugin will allow your app to run without `intl` extension but you will have problem if you want to actually use features which rely on that extension.

I would strongly suggest to switch to a better hosting provider instead. There are numerous cheap / shared hosting available which provide `intl` extension.